# Group Every sunday of a month?

Tags: mysql, database, group-by

I want to `GROUP` every sunday of a month for example on June 2013 would be like this:

- Week 1: 09 June 2013  (Which mean from 1st June to 9th June)
- Week 2: 16 June 2013
- Week 3: 23 June 2013
- Week 4: 30 June 2013

I have tried the SQL query like this:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(statusdate,  '%d-%m-%Y' ) as Week, SUM(sales_points) 
FROM `sales`
   WHERE YEAR(statusdate) = 2013 AND MONTH(statusdate) = 6
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT( statusdate,  '%Y%U')
```

Each week - it count total of points.

The day on the `Week` field turn out to be wrong, it did not match above May example.

Expected result something like that:

```
----------------------
Week        |  Points
----------------------
09-03-2013  |  434
16-03-2013  |  356
23-03-2013  |  354
30-03-2013  |  642
```

Comment: weeks can straddle month boundaries. any week which straddles months 5-6 and 6-7 would be grouped, but you're allowing ONLY month 6 dates.

Comment: @MarcB Yes that would be fine and I think I could use `PHP` to cut it off.

Comment: you might want to change to `month(statusdate) between 5 and 7` to include those straddled weeks.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess...

```
SELECT MIN(dt) FROM calendar WHERE DATE_FORMAT(dt,'%Y-%m') = '2013-06' GROUP BY WEEK(dt);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work...may be a bit messy converting from string but I have used to roll-up weekly data before

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(concat(yearweek(statusdate,1),'Sunday'), '%X%V%W') 
               as week_ending,  
       sum(sales_points) 
from `sales` 
group by STR_TO_DATE(concat(yearweek(statusdate,1),'Sunday'), '%X%V%W')
```